# Get Spill-result to reference correct row #

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

As a result of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67943302/how-to-identify-the-group-of-cells-with-different-pattern-of-numbers-in-the-exce) closed topic I started wondering myself the following:

Let's say we have data like this:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| **1** | a |
| **2** | b |
| **3** | c |
| **4** | a |
| **5** | b |
| **6** | c |
| **7** | g |
| **8** | h |
| **9** | i |

I want to divide the list into 3 (I used `TEXTJOIN`) and check which of the 3 of these is unique.
I used a combination of `MATCH` and `COUNTIF` (and `SEQUENCE`) for this.

Question:
I managed to get that correct, but wanted to get the 3 textjoin-results all at once as a spill range.

In the picture below you can see my results of attempts, but I couldn't get the TEXTJOIN to reference the correct column in it's spill-result. What is missing, or what am I doing wrong?

[image: attempts]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you want for output.

If all you want is to determine which is/are unique entries, just use the `UNIQUE` function.  Note the `exactly_once` argument.

For example:

```
C1: =OR(B1=UNIQUE($B$1:$B$3,,TRUE))
```

and fill down, but the formula will fill down automatically.

[image]

***Edit:***
I don't know how to get the `TEXTJOIN` function to spill down in groups of three like you want.  However, to be able to enter the formula just once, and have the results appear in column B, and have that adjust as you add/remove entries from column A, you can use a Table structure.

In that case, row 1 would be the column headers, and the formula in B2 would be:

```
=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,INDEX([Column1],SEQUENCE(3)+(ROW()-ROW(Table2[#Headers]))*3-3)),"")`
```

No need to fill down.

***Edit2:***

To create a list of unique (listed only once) values from Column B in Column  C, you can use the `UNIQUE` function.  However, due to limitations on `SPILL` functions within a **Table**, this column cannot be part of the table.

In the example below, where Column C is **NOT** part of the table:

```
B2: =IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,INDEX([Column1],SEQUENCE(3)+(ROW()-ROW(Table2[#Headers]))*3-3)),"")
C2: =UNIQUE(Table2[Column2],,TRUE)
```

[image]

***Edit3:***

If you were OK with omitting columnB, and reporting the unique triplets in separate cells instead of concatenated, you could do that with the `UNIQUE` function:

or, without a table,

```
=UNIQUE(INDEX($A:$A,SEQUENCE(COUNTA($A:$A)/3,3,2)),,TRUE)
```

Note that the `start` argument in the `SEQUENCE` function represents the first line of data in column `A`, (`2` in this example)

[image]

Comment: "I managed to get that correct, but wanted to get the 3 textjoin-results all at once as a spill range.

In the picture below you can see my results of attempts, but I couldn't get the TEXTJOIN to reference the correct column in it's spill-result. What is missing, or what am I doing wrong?" So I can get the results, but I want to be able to reference the ranges to be textjoined dynamically, so the formula result would spill out the 3 TEXTJOIN results all at once. I managed to get a spill, but all spill results reference the first range of 3 cells being joined.

Comment: @P.b I don't think you can do that specifically.  Is that your actual goal?  Because if your goal is to have dynamic formulas, which automagically fill down the results as you shorten or lengthen the list in Column A, you can just use a table structure and a slight modification of the formula in column B.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: That's my goal indeed. And as part of that goal it would be to reference to the created spill range, so I would then be able to get the result as shown in column C of my example.

Comment: @P.b If you want a Column to show the unique entries form column 2, listed only once, you can use the `UNIQUE` function.  **However**, it cannot be part of the table as table functions are not allowed to `SPILL`.   See my 2nd Edit.

Comment: I like it. It does what I tried in column D, however with regular ranges it does not work, in table the formula would be copied down until the end of the table and the iferror assures there are no error messages in the remaining cells after the non-error results. Still strange why it's not possible to use something without using "helper" table.

Comment: @P.b I guess things don't always work the way we want.  If you were OK returning the unique triplet elements in separate cells, instead of concatenated, you could do that with the `UNIQUE` function `=UNIQUE(INDEX(Table2[Column1],SEQUENCE(ROWS(Table2)/3,3)),,TRUE)`  or, without a table, `=UNIQUE(INDEX($A:$A,SEQUENCE(COUNTA($A:$A)/3,3,2)),,TRUE)` where the `2` represents the first row of data in column A.

Comment: Cool, the last one would be what I'm looking for: `=textjoin(",",1,UNIQUE(INDEX($A:$A,SEQUENCE(COUNTA($A:$A)/3,3,1)),,TRUE))` for the original data. Not the way I asked, but the desired end result dynamically. I accepted your answer. Well earned!

Comment: @P.b Thanks.  I'll add my last comment to the answer.